# Как скрыть элемент label с помощью js/jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Вот такой div

```
<div class="form-group divPosition">
     <label for="firstName">Имя:</label>
     <input class="form-control inputSize" name="firstName" />
</div>
```

так же есть js/jquery

```
        var elementInput = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        var elementLabel = document.getElementsByTagName('label');         


        for (let i = 0; i < elementInput.length; i++) {
            elementInput[i].addEventListener('blur', func);
            for (let i = 0; i < elementLabel.length; i++) {
                elementLabel[i].addEventListener('blur', funcLabel);
            }
        }

        function func() {
            this.type = 'hidden';
        }

        function funcLabel() {
            ????????????
        }
```

Хочу сделать так, что бы, при заполнении поля input, после того как фокус переходит на следующий input предыдущий скрывался.
**Проблема в следующем:**
Поле input, скрывается как я и хотел, а вот как скрыть **label** не могу понять. Перепробовал кучу вариантов.
 Ничего не помогает.
Единственный вариант, который, хоть как то работал, это 
`$(elementLabel).html("");`,
 но проблема в том, что он убирает, сразу все **label** со страницы, если делаешь так 
`$(this.elementLabel).html("");`
 вообще не работает. Как можно это решить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function func() {
  this.type = 'hidden';
  var label = document.querySelector("label[for='" + this.name + "']");
  if (label)
    label.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо работает! Все нервы себе вымотал!))) А, не могли бы объяснить вот этот синтаксис  `"label[for='" + this.name + "']"` по подробнее что значит [ ] квадратные скобки и что `querySelector` помещает в `var label`?

Comment: @EugeneTM https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css_attribute_selectors.asp